# How to find Google ads inside my page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find all Google ads inside an html page:

```
 jQuery( "object" ).each(function (index){

    if (this.id.contains("google")) {
      var h = jQuery(this).height();
      var w = jQuery(this).width();
      console.log("h:" + h + ",w: " + w); 
    }
```

I'm getting this error: can not call method contains of undefined

1. Anyone can explain why?
2. How do I fix it (or do it in the right way)?

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever you are finding does not have an ID.

Comment: Yes, it have an id....

Comment: Put this as the first line inside the function... `console.log(this.id);`  You will see it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is "can not call method contains of undefined". Since you are calling `this.id.contains`, it means that this.id is undefined, thus, this doesn't have an id property.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: object "name_of_the_id" has no method contains

Comment: @TheGoodGuy then your browser doesn't support the `String.prototype.contains` method. Using IE? or an older version of chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have `.contains()` method. You can use **[.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** instead:

```
jQuery( "object" ).each(function (index){
    if (this.id.indexOf("google") >= 0)
        var h = jQuery(this).height();
        var w = jQuery(this).width();
        console.log("h:" + h + ",w: " + w); 
    }
});
```

Comment: it may not be in all browsers yet, but it does exist https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

Comment: the compatibility chart is out of date too, it works in the current version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while I was doing something similar :
I used jquery selector like this:

```js
alert($('[class*="google"]').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bottomLeaderBoard googleAds">
the content ...
</div>
```

class can be replaced .. 
I hope it help :)